# Avoid deadlock in a single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, glib

I have the following problem: I have a class that needs to be protected from simultaneous access from different threads. The class has two methods: lock() and unlock() using (`g_mutex_lock` / `g_mutex_unlock` with a per-object `GMutex`). Now a locking method looks like this:

```
void Object::method()
{
    lock();
    // do stuff modifying the object
    unlock();
}
```

Now lets assume that I have two mwthods of this type, `method1()` and `method2()` which I call one after another:

```
object.method1();
// but what if some other thread modifies object in between
object.method2();
```

I tried locking the object before this block und unlocking it again, but in this case
there is a deadlock even with a single thread because the `GMutex` doesn't know that it has already been locked by the same thread. A solution would be to modify the method to accept an additional `bool` to determine whether the object is already locked. But is there a more elegant concept? Or is this a shortcoming regarding the design concept in total?

Comment: Can't you use a recursive mutex??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recursive mutex solution mentioned in other responses and comments will work just fine, but in my experience it leads to code that is harder to maintain, because once you switch to a recursive mutex it is all too easy to abuse it and lock all over the place.

Instead, I prefer to reorganize the code so that locking once is sufficient. In your example I would define the class as follows:

```
class Object {
public:
    void method1() {
        GMutexLock scopeLock(&lock);
        method1_locked();
    }
    void method2() {
        GMutexLock scopeLock(&lock);
        method2_locked();
    }
    void method1_and_2() {
        GMutexLock scopeLock(&lock);
        method1_locked();
        method2_locked();
    }

private:
    void method1_locked();
    void method2_locked();

    GMutex lock;
};
```

The "locked" versions of your methods are private, so they are only accessible from inside the class. The class takes responsibility in never calling these without the lock taken.

From the outside you have three choices of methods to call, depending on which of the methods you want to run.

Note that another improvement I've made is to not use explicit locking primitives but instead use the scope indirectly to lock and unlock. This is what `GMutexLock` does. An example implementation for this class is below:

```
class GMutexLock {
private:
    GMutex* m;

    GMutexLock(const GMutexLock &mlock); // not allowed
    GMutexLock &operator=(const GMutexLock &); // not allowed

public:
    GMutexLock(GMutex* mutex) {
        m = mutex;
        g_mutex_lock(m);
    }

    ~GMutexLock() {
        g_mutex_unlock(m);
    }
};
```

Comment: Where is GMutexLock defined? Glib is written in C, there should not be support for RAII should there?

Comment: Actually, I've made a mistake, I found a different GMutex implementation, not the glib one. I'll add an example implementation to my answer, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Added example GLockMutex implementation.

Comment: IMO it is a perfect answer.

Comment: Well, it surely is easy to implement, I was just wondering whether or not this is shipped together with glib, thank you very much Miguel :)

Answer (score 4):

Look up "recursive mutex" or "[reentrant mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)" (versus the non-recursive mutex you're using now). These enable what you want. Some folks are not fans of recursive mutexes and feel they enable messy design.

Note that a recursive mutex cannot be locked on one thread and unlocked on another.

Comment: But does the glib come with a recursive mutex struct? All I see is the GStaticRecMutex. Is it possible to use that mutex be per-object?

Comment: "Some folks are not fans of recursive mutexes and feel they enable messy design." Yea. And locking around the function calls that have locks within them is the messy design they are talking about.

Comment: Well, I look around and it is clear to me now that a recursive mutex is not the answer even though it would work in that case. It is good knowing about them though.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would never use recursive mutexes (especially as such).

I would do some private functions that doesn't lock mutexes and lock around them in public functions' implementations.